# Connect one of 16 loads to power (12 V, ~300 mA), decoder IC?

Tags: power, analog, multiplexer

I am wondering if there is an IC that performs the following task.

If I didn't know any better, then I would probably build the following circuit from discrete components.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUG0ON.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, this seems like such a common necessity! I'm sure that there's an IC for that.

I've managed to come across analog switches and multiplexers, but these seem to be used for low power analog signals, not power.

Is there a circuit that can do this?

Comment: I've made a small edit to,avoid being closed as a "shopping" question.

Comment: There are far-more *specialized* ICs that have OD outputs for driving high(ish)-voltage loads, but none is a demux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are IC's that provide de-muxing as you require, though as mentioned mostly 8/7 bit wide.

TI has a range:

[TPIC6259](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6259.pdf) provides 8 * 45 V FET outputs with either a demux or addressable latch mode.

[TPIC6C595](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpic6c595.pdf) provides a serial to parallel SR (less wires, but not a demux) that reaches 8 * 35 V @ 250 mA if you only have only output on at a time. You can series connect as many as you like.

And of course the FET replacement for the UL2003 type drivers ...the [TPL7407](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpl7407l.pdf) can provide 30 V @600 mA.
Toshiba also have a nice IC that has the diodes for inductive loads built in ...the unfortunately designated [TBD62083](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=29893&prodName=TBD62083AFG)

Comment: "Addressable Latch"! That's the word I didn't know. The '259 is exactly what we need. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahkoe, careful now. OPs question was 300mA 6259 is only rated at 250mA, 595 is <100ma continuous.

Comment: That's OK. We're pulsing the current and we have a less than 1% duty cycle

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use an "addressable latch". Unfortunately, all I can find are 8-output chips. If you have two additional outputs from your micro, you could use two chips that have OE pins.